# Opencart website shows error when uploaded to server

Tags: php, opencart2.3

My opencart websites showed error when i uploaded to server from localhost.
This is the error:

> Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/shopperscart/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myslimki/public_html/index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/shopperscart/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/myslimki/public_html/index.php on line 17 and

I don't know what to do about it. Can someone be kind to put me through as i am quite new to PHP?

Comment: The error message is pretty simple - I looked for a file and I could not find it. Please explain which part of this is confusing to you.

Comment: Update the paths in your config.php file

Answer (score 0):

You hardcoded the absolute path to that file, which is different on the server than it is on your computer. You need to change it to the new absolute path or convert it to a relative path.